# How can I use System.Reflection.Emit to generate a delegate with special input and get the return value?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

For example, we have such a class:

```cs
public class Message
{
    public SayType Say(string name)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello," + name);
        return SayType.Name;
    }
}

public enum SayType
{
    Name
}
```

And this is my emit code:

```cs
DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = 
    new DynamicMethod("Say",typeof(SayType),new Type[]{typeof(string)});
var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);//Non-static
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,typeof(Message).GetMethods()[0]);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
System.Delegate delegates = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, SayType>));
List<System.Delegate> list = new List<System.Delegate>();
list.Add(delegates);
foreach (var func in list.Cast<Func<string,SayType>>())
{
    func("e");
}
```

And I got the errors:

```cs
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime det
ected an invalid program.
   at Say(String )
```

And I aslo tried use such a statement.

```cs
System.Delegate delegates = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, SayType>));
delegates.DynamicInvoke("ha");
```

I aslo get the errors:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has
been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invali
d program.
   at Say(String )
```

Why I get these errors?

And how can I solve the errors and get the delegate of `Message.Say`?

Comment: So you're trying to generate a method which calls your `Message.Say` method? Can you post the C# equivalent of the code you're trying to generate?

Comment: @canton7 Yes. I want to use emit to generate Message.Say and get the delegate of Message.Say. I want to reduce the cost of reflection so I try this thing.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @PalleDue Sorry, and I have edited the question.

Comment: Where do you get the `Message` instance from, to call the `Say` method on? That's the bit you're missing

Comment: @canton7 Thank you, but how can I generate Message Instance and bind the Say method with the instance?

Comment: Where do you want the `Message` instance to come from? Do you want to pass it into the delegate, or do you want to do `new Message()` in your IL?

Comment: @canton7 I want to pass it into the delegate

Comment: OK, so modify you delegate signature to accept it, then `ldarg` it then `ldarg` the `string` parameter, then `callvirt`. When you call an instance method, the first thing it takes from the stack is the instance to call the method on, then the second and subsequent parameters are taken from the stack

Comment: Also no need to use `ldarg_1` or `ldarg_s` explicitly. Just do `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 1);` and `ILGenerator` will turn it into a shorted `ldarg_1` or `ldarg_s` if possible

Comment: @canton7 Thank you very much! I have solved it! But when I trying to make a generic delegate it told me:Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: The number of generic arguments p
rovided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition. (Parameter 'inst
antiation')
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code

Comment: @canton7 I have posted another question, thank you.